# Doctrine change namespace on generate entities

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine-orm

I'm using Laravel-Doctrine. I created my mappings with "annotation style"  in `app/Models` (but without getters and setters) and now want to generate the entities including the methods.

But running `php artisan doctrine:generate:entities` keeps the same namespace for generated entities.

So either, it overwrites my mappings or (if I update the source path in `config/doctrine.php`) it generates the entities in a different folder but keeps the same namespace as specified in the mappings. This leads to duplicate declaration in namespace.

How can I change the namespace for generated entities?? The current way is really a usage pain.

Answer (score 0):

I hacked it this way:

```
// config/doctrine.php

'paths' => [
   base_path('database/mappings')
],
```

Create basic mapping entities with annotation style in `database/mappings`, but without setters and getters. And do not set any namespace. If you like to extend your mapping class, you need to use `require_once()` to import it.

Then run:

```
php artisan doctrine:generate:entities --generate-annotations --generate-methods --regenerate-entities
```

This will generate full entities in `app/Entities`. After run custom cleanup script, to insert namespace declaration to the generated entities.

```
php -f database/mapping-tools/clear-entity-namespace.php
```

***File: clear-entity-namespace.php***

```
<?php

$targetDir = 'app/Entities';
$files = scandir($targetDir);
array_shift($files); // remove .
array_shift($files); // remove ..

foreach ($files as $file) {
   echo '> File: ' . $file . PHP_EOL;
   $path = $targetDir . '/' . $file;
   $content = file_get_contents($path);

   $newHeader = '<?php ' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL . 'namespace Entities;';
   $content = str_replace('<?php', $newHeader, $content);
   file_put_contents($path, $content);
}

echo '>>> Cleanup complete' . PHP_EOL;
```